# How to Improve Vora Performance

Tags: vora

I have been running some tests in both Vora and Hive from the Sap Spark Controller as well as a Base Spark Server. Both the Controller and the Spark Thrift server have the same configurations.

12 Column
10M row table
680Mb

Both Spark Server and SAP Controller are started with --master YARN and the same number of executors,executor memory and cores. The Controller and The Thrift Server are found on the same server in the Hadoop Cluster, I run one test shutdown that Controller/Thriftserver, then startup another to test.

All Numbers Below are from the **Thrift Server Job Completion Time** or **SAP Controller Job Completion Time**, I am not waiting for the results to show in HANA or in Beeline or Spark-Shell.

Results:

**Spark-Shell -> Spark Thriftserver -> Hive**
Select Column returns in : 13s
Count returns in : 1.2s

**Spark-Shell -> Spark Thriftserver -> Vora**
Select Column returns in : 5s
Count returns in : 100ms

**Hana -> Sap Controller -> Hive**
Select Column returns in : 45s
Count returns in : 4s

**Hana -> Sap Controller -> Vora**
Select Column returns in : 24s
Count returns in : 2.1s

**Beeline -> Spark Thriftserver -> Hive**
Select Column returns in : 35s
Count returns in : 1.9s

**Beeline -> Spark Thriftserver -> Vora**
Select Column returns in : 55s
Count returns in : 1.2s

Are there any important performance tuning tips to help the controller? The fact that I can select from Hive at a faster speed than the Controller can from Vora is interesting.

Comment: By default, Spark does not use Hive SerDe libraries to read/write data files, it uses its own libs. Plus, in interactive mode, Spark does not incur the overhead of allocating YARN containers and starting a distributed batch job just to read a few records. So an interesting reference would be the performance from a Beeline JDBC client.

Comment: Added a new section at the bottom for the Beeline through Spark to Hive. The Spark Server was started with --master Yarn, aswell as the SAP Controller and Spark used by beeline. Is there a way to connect Beeline to Vora?

Comment: What does "Beeline -> Spark -> XXX" mean? Are you connecting to the Spark Thriftserver? Another consideration is that with the HANA Spark Controller you connect from a (remote) HANA system to your Hadoop cluster - which might add network cost to the total time. Then if you use HANA Studio from yet another server it will add more network time to show you the result. Maybe you can add some info regarding your node locations and how the times were actually measured.

Comment: I have added a bit more info in the question above. I only measure the time it takes for the executors to finish the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of Partitioning changes. I have gotten SAP Controller to select the data at a faster rate from **Hive**, Vora still is about the same speed.
It seems that smaller number of splits helps the Controller tremendously
Splitting the data from 31 to 10 files decreases the query time by more than 75%

current results:

**Spark-Shell -> Spark Thriftserver -> Hive**
Select Column returns in : 14s
Count returns in : 1s

**Hana -> Sap Controller -> Hive**
Select Column returns in : 10s
Count returns in : 5s

**Beeline -> Spark Thriftserver -> Hive**
Select Column returns in : 7s
Count returns in : 1.3s

The count seems to return slowly still but not a problem.